# Retrieve the Last-Modified headers of all the item resources of a collection resource in one single HTTP GET request

Tags: http, collections, request, header, last-modified

How to retrieve the `Last-Modified` headers of all the item resources of a collection resource in one single HTTP GET request?

For instance let's say the URI of the collection resource is:

> https://api.example.com/collection/

and the URIs of the item resources are:

> https://api.example.com/collection/item1
>   https://api.example.com/collection/item2
>   https://api.example.com/collection/item3
>   […]
>   https://api.example.com/collection/itemN

Comment: I guess the only way to implement this is: assemble all `Last-Modified` headers on server side and expose a new API for such assembled information.

Comment: @shaochuancs I think that I can even embed the `Last-Modified` information of each child resource in the collection resource's representation (`https://api.example.com/collection/`). JSON HAL has a dedicated `_embedded` key for that: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

When bundling information of many request to one, you need some kind of logic, which does the request and exposes the information. You can achieve this by implementing the logic at many levels (e.g. using your webserver to bundle the requests or having a "new" web service, which performs the requests and responses with the full information).

In your case I would suggest to create a new webservice (e.g. at https://api.example.com/collection/all) or edit the existing serive at https://api.example.com/collection/ to bundle the information of the items and to serve the `Last-Modified` information (or even more) from all items.

You can use e.g. a small PHP script using curl to get all the required information.